# PHP version supposedly wrong, but seems to be correct

Tags: php, grav

I am trying to make a bash script on my server to clear the Grav cache. When I run it from the server, it works fine. But when I run it from my local machine, over SSH, I get an error: `You are running PHP 5.6.36, but Grav needs at least PHP 7.1.3 to run`. However, `php -v` on my server returns `PHP 7.2.11 (cli)` and on my local machine returns `PHP 7.1.23 (cli)`. I do not begin to understand what the problem might be.

In the end, I could not resolve the issue of the different PHP versions, but solved the problem by including the path to the correct PHP version in the server script. So, locally I have `ssh jeremygrav@ps589716.dreamhostps.com "bash ./clear.sh"` and on the server, the script contains `/usr/local/php73/bin/php bin/grav cache --all`.

That works fine, although I realise it avoids the problem rather than solving it.

Comment: Check your server configuration. Maybe your webserver uses php-fpm which is different.

Comment: @MarkusZeller The question says he's getting the error when he runs it in the CLI, not the webserver.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, so check the config to see if it is a different php version. Please read what I wrote stating that.

Comment: How are you running the BASH script?  Under which user account, environment.  Try simply writing out the PHP_VERSION when called the same to confirm.   You can have multiple versions installed, and may need to use a different path to the binary.

Comment: Can you clarify how you run it from the server and it works fine?

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect the solution I am using.

Comment: Sounds like you just need to set your `PATH` environment variable to include the `/usr/local/php73/bin` directory, or put a symlink to PHP 7 in `/usr/bin`.